# Call 1 time a function each day

Tags: php, date

I want to call php function 1 time a day.
I pick a picture out the database and I'll show it on my website.
Next day is there another picture random out the database.

I want to call getRandomPicture once a day.

```
public function getRandomPicture(){This function picks a image out the database}
```

Comment: Memcached or a vale date from the db, you compare and boom

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to call a function that sets a flag on an image to mark it as picture of the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that, would be by:

1) Add the code to a PHP file (the function execution).

2) Call the php file using a cron job once a day

Example:

**getrandom.php content:**

```
<?php
public function getRandomPicture(){This function picks a image out the database} 
getRandomPicture();
?>
```

**Cron:**

`0 * * *    * php /path/to/your/script/getrandom.php`

The `0 * * * *` will call the file that will run the function, once a day, at midnight.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use cronjobs. Another  possibility is to use events inside your MySQL database (if you have one): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 0):

You are probable searching for something like [CRON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), see [example](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/). Trigger PHP script with calling this function which probably pick and save picture for later use.